# Can we apply Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution law on non-identical particles? Can we apply it on astro-physical systems?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, astrophysics

I was wondering whether we can apply Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution law on particles with different masses and composition.

Also, is it possible to apply it on an astro-physical systems like planets and stars?

Answer (score 0):

The Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution applies to any substance, pure or mixed, gas or liquid or solid –*at equilibrium*. Air, for example, a mixture of nitrogen, oxygen and other species with various moilecular masses, follows the MB distribution when in equilibrium.

If by "particles" you mean macroscopic objects such as stones, or stars, themselves made of molecules, then the general answer is no.

From a mathematical standpoint the MB would give the distribution of velicities in a system of "particles" of any kind, micro- or macro-scopic, if the system has an equal probability to be in any microstate with the same energy when the volume and number of "particles" is constant. That's a big "if".